# Calculated column value for Yes/No field in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column, dashboard-designer-2013

I am developing a KPi, where am using a column named Complete which contains Yes/No field in it. For this if i write a calculated value for yes/no field:

```
=IF(CompletedTask=1,"Yes","No")
```

its not working. What should be the correct calcualted value for this field. IF Yes it should display 1 and no means 0. It should set the value using this calculation. thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3):

The correct formula should be like that:

```
=IF([CompletedTask], "Yes", "No")
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try it like this:

```
=IF([CompletedTask]=1, "Yes", "No")
```

below is the reference for other formulas:

[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx)